# Restore Tab key function

Tags: keyboard-layout, xfce, vnc

I am not very proficient in Linux and have to deal with it because it is part of working environment (hardware hosts of measuring equipment). It is accessed remotely over VNC and has XFCE as desktop environment (but it is Ubuntu 16.04).

The problem is that the Tab key stopped working normally:

- instead of autocompleting the paths in Terminal it cycles through them

It is worth mentioning that I haven't tried to modify the key function and that another user on the same machine doesn't have the problem.

I'd like to restore it's usual function

Comment: Sometimes the ALT key gets "stuck." Did you try to press and release the ALT key a few times?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It is not the case:  Alt+Tab works as usual by cycling through all windows (while Tab as of now cycles only through terminals)

Comment: so just to make sure i get it right, you are accessing ubuntu remotely using VNC and at that point the tab is not working as it should? If so, what OS are you on when using VNC?

Comment: @SimpliFixed Yes. The Linux machine (and correspondingly VNC server) has been restarted multiple times. I have Win 10.

The tab key works normally for a different user under all the same circumustances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by clearing the shortcut for "switch window for same application" in the Xfce Window manager